# sharedContainerIdentifier on NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm adding a Widget extension to an iOS app.  The Widget needs to make network calls, sharing the cookies set during the main app's login process.  The `NSURLConfiguration`'s `sharedContainerIdentifier` is perfect for this.  Since we're already using App Groups this was easy to implement.

The main app is mostly on `NSURLSession`, but has some old `NSURLConnection` code.  Does a mechanism exist to use `NSURLConnection` with a `sharedContainerIdentifier`?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways:

1. You can use `+[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedCookieStorageForGroupContainerIdentifier:]` to obtain the shared cookie store, then manage cookies yourself using a custom `NSURLProtocol` sublass registered in the shared (global) protocol namespace.  In that custom protocol, extract any new cookies from responses and inject any matching cookies into requests.  Then tag the requests (so you don't process them twice) and pass them back into the `NSURLConnection` machinery.
2. You can do the above, but instead of managing cookies in the shared cookie jar, use `NSURLSession` to issue the requests in a session configured with your shared container identifier.
3. You can swizzle the `NSURLConnection` methods and replace them with `NSURLSession` calls.

None of these approaches is likely to be easier than modernizing the code and converting it to use `NSURLSession` unless there are third-party closed-source libraries involved.